# Representing tuples with multiple types as JSON in python

Tags: javascript, python, json, dictionary

I have a tuple (could also use list instead) like this:

```
 (1, 'jsmith', 'Ferrari', '10 million', 39, 16, 2, 0, '-')
```

What would be a sensible way to represent this as a JSON struct in python? The key is a string like so:

```
 { 
    "John Smith" : (1, 'jsmith', 'Ferrari', '10 million', 39, 16, 2, 0, '-') 
 }
```

Any suggestions? The JSON will be parsed in JS in the front end and will always be the same length. Missing entries are represented by '-'.

Comment: Have a look at [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps)

Comment: Is the problem that you don't know how to turn that `dict` into a string representing the JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps).

```
>>> import json
>>> data = (1, 'jsmith', 'Ferrari', '10 million', 39, 16, 2, 0, '-')
>>> json.dumps({'John Smith': data})
'{"John Smith": [1, "jsmith", "Ferrari", "10 million", 39, 16, 2, 0, "-"]}'
```

BTW, [JSON](http://json.org/) has only array (`[...]`); no distinction between `list` and `tuple`.

Answer (score 1):

Represent a list as an array, i.e. beginning with `[` and ending with `]`.